# Test Configuration Parameter - Tosca

Tags: tosca

My Tosca test case folder will have 5 test cases each with

1. Test case from Library - Open URL
2. Functionality checks

This URL may change but the functionalities are the same.

Is there any way to keep this URL as variable so that I can run the functionalities in any URL I input?

The URL should be generalized for the Test case folder

Answer (score 0):

You can create library with open url module and create business parameter for url. This way you can easily change url every time